# WCF service - connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

For most clients this service works regular, but some clients very often get this error when making requests on this WCF service.

(Note: WCF service send response but client doesn't get any data)

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while
>   receiving the **HTTP** response to **https**://xxxxx:1400/Exxxxxe.svc.
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an **HTTP** request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details.
>
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
>   receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: **Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host**.
>
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)    at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request,
>   Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Any idea?

Comment: I had this problem, the service never gets the message (that means that if you trace the service, there's no activity log for this comunication), and client report this error, so there's no clue. Where are you running the service? OS? Is there any proxy in the middle?

Comment: Hello SelvirK, Were you able to fix this issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: Some required properties has a null value.